# Inherits in Java

Tags: java

```
class Box
{
    // Instance Variables
    double length, ipsos;
    double width, mikos;
    double height, platos;

    // Constructors
    public Box ( double side )
    {
        width = side;
        height = side;
        length = side;
    }

    public Box ( double x , double y , double z)
    {
        platos = y;
        ipsos = z;
        mikos = x;
    }

    // Methods
    double calculate(double praksi)
    {
        return 2 * ( width * height +
                width * length +
                height * length ) ;
    }

    double volume(double emvadon)
    {
        return platos * ipsos * mikos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Volume: " + volume(1) + "\n Calculate: " + calculate(1);
    }
}
```

How can we create a class that inherits MyBox class Box and will be used only for cubes by writing a constructor to ensure the creation of a cube using the second constructor of Box that takes three arguments and in case of an error initializing the cube MyBox to print error message?

I am very new at java, so please explain as simple as possible.

Comment: First, I recommend creating a class that inherits `Box`, named `MyBox` (note: use it only for cubes). Next I would write a constructor that ensures the creation of a cube by using the second constructor of `Box` (the one that takes 3 arguments). By the way, in case of an error while initializing the cube, you may wish to print an error message.

Comment: how i use an other class constructor to a new one?
and should i use if command for the error message?

Comment: The `super` keyword can be used to call one of the superclass constructors from a subclass constructor. Check out the official tutorial on the [`super` keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html), it is short and easy to read, and will give you a good idea of how to proceed.

Comment: As for the error, it depends. If your `MyBox` constructor also takes 3 parameters, then yes, you would need to use some combination of `if` statements to check if all 3 parameter were the same. However, if you go with the technique in David Wallace's answer, then the sides will *always* be the same (although you still may want to check other things, e.g. make sure the side length is positive, etc.)

Comment: By the way, I've seen your other questions here. You seem to be slowly asking us to do this entire assignment for you one step at a time. You should really consider making a bit of effort on your own.

Comment: i just need a push to understand some things , and then ill go alone.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little confused by why `Box` has two constructors, and six fields.  I would have thought that one constructor and three fields would be enough.  But assuming you keep the constructor with three parameters, you can call it from your `Cube` constructor like this.

The line starting `super` specifies which `Box` constructor the `Cube` constructor should call, and what to pass it.  This guarantees that a `Cube` will always have all three dimensions equal.

```
public class Cube extends Box {
    public Cube(double side) {
        super(side, side, side);
    }
}
```